# Avoid objects from pointing to the same underlying object

Tags: python

Can someone explain why in the following example all functions are the same after running? Is there a way to avoid this and get the distinct function I want (please don't suggest using partial).

```
def lin_fun(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b

funs = {}
params = [(1,2), (3,4)]

for param in params:
    funs[param] = lambda x: lin_fun(x, *param)
    
print(funs[params[0]](100))
# prints 304
print(funs[params[1]](100))
# prints 304
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how name binding in loops works.

You'll need one more stack frame to properly capture values:

```
def bind(f, *params):
    return lambda x: f(x, *params)

for param in params:
    funs[param] = bind(lin_fun, *param)
```